# Reloading URLs with anchors vs navigating to URLs with anchors

Tags: javascript, html

What's the difference between navigating to a URL with an anchor and actually clicking refresh on the page?

There is a boatload of probable JavaScript conflict on the page I'm debugging but I've noticed that pressing refresh in the browser doesn't cause the issue, whereas actually clicking into the URL bar, not editing the URL, and pressing enter does.

The URL has an anchor tag in it, eg: `//foo.bar/page#blah`

If someone can break it down in terms of events or any kind of vanilla JavaScript speak I'd be infinitely appreciative.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some details about the conflict, such as what happens when you refresh (`F5`/`control-R`) vs `alt-D-enter`? The difference between them is that the first will issue a HTTP request to the server to reload the page, whereas the second does not - it is the same as clicking on a `<a href='#foo'></a>` which will simply scroll `<tag id=foo'>` into view (local navigation).

Comment: I've more or less isolated where the issue is, it's more that there's probably something like 1000 files all trying to do different things in the great miasma that is this page, so I trust nothing lol.

Comment: But thank you that makes a lot of sense, will report back if I find anything further. I'm mostly interested in how the browser is handling the difference.

Comment: [Here's a list of JS events that might happen during navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) - if the JS code hooks into this it *could* be that it 'thinks' the page is freshly being loaded with the alt-D+enter method. and trying to initialize stuff that's already initialized. If you have a link to a demo site, or some browser console error messages, that would help to get the question answered. Happy bug-hunting ;)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! :)